# Creating a PCB for my MCU

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, lpc

So I have an NXP-LPC1313DFB48 MCU and I want to create a PCB from scratch so that I could connect my FTDI RS232 cable to it and program the MCU. What parts would I need to do this and what steps would I take to build this PCB?

Product page of the cable: http://www.newark.com/jsp/search/productdetail.jsp?SKU=34M8872
Product page of the MCU: http://www.newark.com/jsp/search/productdetail.jsp?SKU=83T7141

Answer (score 2):

Get a piece of software such as Fritzing, EAGLE, or gEDA where you can create the schematic with the components you need and create the PCB layout once complete. You then send the files (or their exported equivalents) to a PCB fab that will create the PCB for you for a price and post back the results. You can then either solder the components on yourself or send them along with the PCB to an assembly service.

Comment: In addition, you should check the data sheet for the necessary support components. For example, it may require certain regulated voltages, decoupling capacitors, crystals, etc. And, yes, this is often a *lot* of reading to do to make sure you get everything right. This is why development boards are very popular products for MCU developers. If you've never made a PCB yourself before, it's almost certainly easier and cheaper to find a development board/kit that contains the CPU you need already made.